# VBA code to hide a group of pivot chart+graphics+shapes+slicers

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a group of pivot chart+graphics+shapes+slicers that I gathered just for the purpose of being able to move on the sheet - I have a pivot chart behind them. 
I want to toggle the visibility of this group (or all the elements together) with one button.
Here is my code that is returning an error "Object doesn't support this property of method"

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
With ToggleButton1
If .Value Then
    .Caption = "Hide Graph"
    Sheets("CHART").Objects.Range(Array("Chart 1", "Straight Connector 7", "TextBox 5", "Customer" [slicer], "Customer Group"[slicer])).Visible = True
    Sheets("CHART").Objects.Range(Array("Chart 1", "Straight Connector 7", "TextBox 5", "Customer", "Customer Group")).Activate
 Else
    .Caption = "Show Graph"
    Sheets("CHART").Objects.Range(Array("Chart 1", "Straight Connector 7", "TextBox 5", "Customer", "Customer Group")).Visible = False
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Thank you

**EDIT**

This code works with :

`Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
With ToggleButton1
    If .Value Then
        .Caption = "Hide Graph"
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group 8").Visible = True
    Else
        .Caption = "Show Graph"
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group 8").Visible = False
    End If
End With
End Sub`

Comment: If its a 'group' then try hiding the group by name.  Example: `ActiveSheet.Shapes("myGroup").Visible = False`

Comment: Thank you. These changes helped:

Comment: @PortlandRunner noted, thanks.